# What does actutally Bottom overflowed by 123 pixels mean in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am learning flutter and currently switched from android to flutter.In flutter i mostly get an error something like 
`bottom overflowed by 234 pixels` or `renderbox overflowed by 340 pixels`.And i fixes that problem by increase the height of the widget.If so then how to know that what much size giving to widget.I mean in android we can  declare the height of the layout to be wrap content and its works perfectly.Please explain me that how can i avoid this situation because if i fixes the issue by changing the height of widget in one device then in devices of other screen sizes if throws same error ?Here is a image which throws an error.Ignore the red error , see the error in below screen.Thanks in advance.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA05O.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give fixed width and height to your widgets wrap it with SizedBox.
You can specify fixed width and height and you child widget will be the exact dimension.

If you want one of the dimension fixed and the other as big as the parent widget, you can try something like this:

```
SizedBox(
  width: double.inifinity,
  height: 50.0
  child: Conttainer()
 )
```

If you are worried about giving fixed dimensions. You can give the height or width according to the ratio of the screen size. You can get the height and width of the screen like this:

> double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

Use the above value to give the width to your widgets like below:

```
Container(
  width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
  height: 100,
 )
```

To answer question in the comment. You can do the following to wrap the text with dynamic content.

```
ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxWidth: 100
      ),
      child: Text(
        'ADASFASF ssss'
      ),
    )
```

The above code will wrap the text to next line if the text widget is more than 100 pixels wide. As we don't have any constraints on the height.

Comment: suppose container container widget contains text widget and the text data is dynamic recieved from server and the data can be of one line to bunch of lines in that case do how do i know how much size a widget to give ? considering different devices having different screen sizes

Comment: in that case if your height is double.infinity the text will wrap to the next line

Comment: Also you can try using ConstrainedBox for wrapping the text.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow happens when the minimum size of a child widget is bigger than the parent's constraints (width and/or height).

Which means you can:

- make the parent widget bigger (eg: SizedBox(height:, width:,))
- make the child smaller (eg: using a FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.scaleDown) widget)

Though the first method will not allow you a size bigger than the parent's parent widget. It should be enough to build the children relatively to their parents and not the other way.

In your case, it seems like you text + image widget is taking a little too much space. I recommend wrapping it in a FittedBox that will scale down the child widget until it fits in you bottom bar.

```dart
FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
  child: _buildChildWidget(),
)
```

You can then wrap it in other widgets to build the layout you want (Row, Expanded, Flexible, LayoutBuilder, ...).

As the overflow issue usually happens because text or images are too big. A good exercise is trying to make your app work while setting text size to the maximum value allowed by the accessibility options of your device. You can do the same with images by setting an image size relative to your text size for example.

Paddings and margins can also cause problems because they leave less space for the child widget.